# Probability box of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, combinations

I have to solve next task: There is box with 12 red cards, 8 blue cards and 7 green cards. Four cards are taken from it, and must find:
a) probability to has 2 red, 1 blue and 1 green card
b) all 4 cards to be the same color:

My logic: a)
$$\frac{C\frac{2}{12}.C\frac{1}{8}.C\frac{1}{7}}{C\frac{4}{27}} = \frac{66.8.7}{17550} = \frac{3696}{17550} = 0.21$$
b) $$\frac{ C\frac{4}{12} }{ C\frac{4}{27} } + \frac{C\frac{4}{8}}{\frac{4}{27}} + \frac{C\frac{4}{7}}{C\frac{4}{27}} = \frac{11880}{421200} + \frac{1680}{421200} + \frac{840}{421200} = \frac{14400}{421200} = 0.034$$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: What is the meaning of e.g. $C\frac2{12}$? I would expect $\binom{12}2$ but that equals $144$ and not $66$. There are mistakes in your calculations. Maybe not in your logic.

Comment: @drhab means that 2 red cards are pricked from 12 red cards = $\frac{12.11}{1.2}$

Comment: Then everything is okay (not you, but I made a mistake in calculating it). Except the $C$ in terms like $C\frac{11880}{421200}$. That is most probably a typo.

Comment: In part b, there should only be Cs in the first expression.  Otherwise, your answer is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig add this as an answer please

Comment: Since your revised answer is correct (although I would have written $\approx 0.21$ in the first question and $\approx 0.034$ in the second), I will focus on your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in combinatorics notation, but the final answers are OK. In question b), you shouldn't use the combinatorics notation in the second step and on, just in the first expression.

I mean:

a) $\frac{\binom{12}2\binom{8}1\binom{7}1}{\binom{27}4}=\frac{3969}{17550}=0.2105$ 
b) $\frac{\binom{12}4+\binom{8}4+\binom{7}4}{\binom{27}4}=\frac{495+70+35}{17550}=\frac{600}{17550}=0.034$

Comment: @TeodorKolev, here is the example you asked for. I hope it is useful.